# Services returning JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have heard about JSONPand want to try it with a live service (except flickr). Can anyone give me a very simple example in jquery/javascript on how to call this service? Also how do I pull large images (> 1MB) efficiently. Is there a way to add a progress bar during the call

Comment: Hi User, on Stack Overflow, you should post a question about a real, actual problem that you're facing. Asking for a list of JSONP services is not a good question for Stack Overflow. Please make an [edit] to your question and modify it so it asks a more specific question about JSONP. Good luck!

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html

Comment: You should also Ask (a new) Question when you have a new question. Editing it into a three week old, unrelated question that has been closed and already has an accepted answer isn't going to provide you with good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter, Flickr, WUnderground etc..